# User Profile details not showing up after migrating from 2013 to O365

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2013, office-365, migration

I recently migrated a site from SP 2013 to O365, when I goto the permissions page (`_layouts/15/user.aspx`) and open up any group, I can see that the users are present in the group,but the title and description fields are not populated.

It is showing up in the 2013 site, but its empty in O365. Delve and Azure AD seems to have the title and department details.

When I add a user who has title and description on a different site to this site, the fields still don't show up. Does it take time for the user profile details to show up?

Any insights on what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0):

User Profile Sync timer job’s run frequency cannot be changed, which occurs during regularly scheduled one-way synchronization—which should occur at least every 24 hours. If you can see all the properties in AAD and Delve, that seems the user profiles are fine.

You can wait for some time and see if the fields are updated or not. If not, raise a service request